# Clear scroll request clearing the in progress scroll

Tags: elasticsearch, scroll

I am facing `Trying to create too many scroll contexts` issue in production.
ES Version 7.11.2

The temporary solution I have been applying is

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/_cluster/settings" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{
    "persistent" : {
        "search.max_open_scroll_context": 5000
    },
    "transient": {
        "search.max_open_scroll_context": 5000
    }
}
```

For permanent solution, I went through the documentation which recommends to [clear scroll requests](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.8/java-rest-high-clear-scroll.html#java-rest-high-clear-scroll-request). The solution I have implemented is

```
private Iterator<SearchHit> getNextSearchHits() throws IOException {
            if (searchResponse.getScrollId() == null) {
                return Collections.emptyIterator();
            }

            SearchScrollRequest searchScrollRequest = new SearchScrollRequest(searchResponse.getScrollId())
                  .scroll(scrollTimeoutMinutes);
            ClearScrollRequest clearScrollRequest = new ClearScrollRequest();
            clearScrollRequest.addScrollId(searchResponse.getScrollId());
            System.out.println("scroll id " + searchResponse.getScrollId());
            searchResponse = esClient.scroll(searchScrollRequest, requestOptions);
            ClearScrollResponse response = esClient.clearScroll(clearScrollRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
            return searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
            if (hits.length > 0) {
                UnmodifiableIterator<SearchHit> searchHitsIterator = Iterators
                      .forArray(hits);
                return searchHitsIterator;
            }
            return Collections.emptyIterator();
        }
```

`searchResponse` is a global variable.

But the "clear scroll request" results into `ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=search_context_missing_exception, reason=No search context found for id [2]]]` because the scroll id from the search response remains the same for the next request. What's a better way of solving this problem? I do not want to increase the value of `search.max_open_scroll_context` as a permanent solution.

Comment: Why do you have so many scroll requests kept open? What are you using the Scroll API for?

Comment: Its a scan and scroll to fetch the documents. Did you mean to ask the business use case?

Comment: Yes, the business use case and why you reach 5000 concurrent scroll requests

Comment: Does that mean there are 5000 scroll ids in use at the same time?

Comment: It means you have started 5000 scroll request without closing them when you were done with them. Each scroll request maintains a context/state open until you clear it or it times out. Failing to do so can impair your cluster.

Comment: Found out, the scroll alive time was 30 mins which should be the cause of problem

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out!